# Get item from first list of list inside list - java 8

Tags: lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have two lists and I need check the max rate and when find it, retrieve bankConversionFees item

```
for (BankConversionFees bankConversionFees : allFees) {
    for (FeesHistory hist : bankConversionFee.getFeesHistory()) {
        //check FeesHistory with max value of hist.getRate()
    }
}
```

The classes:

```
public class BankConversionFees{
 private String name;
 private List<FeesHistory> feesHistory;
}

public class FeesHistory {
private Double rate;
}
```

I achieved the result with the code below but I'm not sure if it's the best way

```
Comparator<FeesHistory> comparator = Comparator.comparingDouble(FeesHistory::getRate);
FeesHistory maxFees = allFees.stream() //
                .filter(bank -> !bank.getFeesHistory().isEmpty()) //
                .map(bank -> bank.getFeesHistory().stream().max(comparator).get()) //
                .max(comparator).get();
    
Optional<BankConversionFee> maxBank = allFees.stream() //
                .filter(bank -> !bank.getFeesHistory().isEmpty()) //
                .filter(bank -> bank.getFeesHistory().contains(maxFees)) //
                .map(b -> b) //
                .findFirst();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conceptually this can be reframed as trying to get the "greatest" `BankConversionFees`, where "greatest" means the one containing the single greatest individual rate.

This can be represented in a simple, straightforward manner using [`Stream.max(Comparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#max(java.util.Comparator)) with a comparator that compares the `BankConversionFees` based on the largest rate (treating any empty fee history lists as smaller than any non-emtpy ones):

```java
Comparator<BankConversionFees> comparator = Comparator.comparing(
        f -> f.getFeesHistory().stream().map(FeesHistory::getRate).max(Comparator.naturalOrder()),
        Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.comparing(o -> o.orElse(null))));

return allFees.stream().max(comparator);
```

If you want to continue to return an empty optional in the case where no `BankConversionFees` has any rates, as opposed to returning one of the fees without rates, you can filter accordingly:

```java
Comparator<BankConversionFees> comparator = Comparator.comparing(
        h -> h.getFeesHistory().stream().map(FeesHistory::getRate).max(Comparator.naturalOrder()).orElseThrow());

return allFees.stream().filter(f-> !f.getFeesHistory().isEmpty()).max(comparator);
```

Comment: Hi M.Justin. It gave the same result of my approach, but in a cleaner way. Thanks!